# How can I load js files in specific pages using jQueryMobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

It's a known fact that jQueryMobile loads pages with ajax and is not including in DOM the header content in every pages.

I need to load a custom js file in some pages, how can I achieve this? Until now I have placed the .js files in the body, but there are some problems with the code there too so it's not a good workaround. Until I can find a solution I will use the `rel="external"` workaround, but I really need to find an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some javascript to dynamically add the js file to the DOM.

This is demoed here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Comment: I need a solution that requires minimal implementation time(and specific to jqueryMobile), otherwise i will use the rel=external workaround i described. Anyway, thanks for the answer

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-equivalent-of-document-ready may help you out then

Comment: Thanks @Allen, the approach seems pretty solid and i will definetively try it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try including the custom script within the data-role="page" div in pages where you want to use those javascript.

From JQM docs:

> Another approach for page-specific scripting would be to include
>   scripts at the end of the body element. If you include your custom
>   scripting this way, be aware that these scripts will execute when that
>   page is loaded via Ajax or regular HTTP, so if these scripts are the
>   same on every page, you'll likely run into problems. If you're
>   including scripts this way, we'd recommend enclosing your page content
>   in a data-role="page" element, and placing scripts that are referenced
>   on every page outside of that element. Scripts that are unique to that
>   page can be placed in that element, to ensure that they execute when
>   the page is fetched via Ajax.

Comment: actually this is the method i used but recently i runned into problems (events triggering twice)  and start searching ways to include js files in head instead of body