# Page specific scripts are not loading with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using jquery mobile and phonegap to create an android application.  I followed the short guide "20 Recipes for Programming Phonegap" which recommends using a callback from a custom script loaded on index.html to a function named `onPageLoad()` where Page is the name of the destination page's html file.

I'm stuck however, because the javascript, which I included inside the data-role="page" div with a script tag, is not loading.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8838639/153382 points to the jQuery mobile guide that says this should work.  I've read the guide, it's not working.  Now what?

Has something changed with jquery mobile that makes this no longer work?

**Update**
Some testing shows that inline scripts run, but the script src attribute is not being evaluated for the script I am trying to load from a file.

also tried `<script type="text/javascript">$.getScript("js/lookup.js");</script>`.  It did not work either.

**code**

common.js included on index.html after `<div data-role="page">...</div>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/common.js"></script>
```

relevant contents of common.js:

```
function executeCallback() {
    if (isPhoneGapReady) {
        // get name of current html page
        var pages = currentUrl.split("/");
        var currentPage = pages[pages.length - 1].
            slice(0, pages[pages.length - 1].indexOf(".html"));

        // captalize the first letter and execute the function
        currentPage = currentPage.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
            currentPage.slice(1);

        if (typeof window['on' + currentPage + 'Load'] ==
            typeof(Function)) {
            window['on' + currentPage + 'Load']();
        }
        alert('on' + currentPage + 'Load: ' + typeof window['on' + currentPage + 'Load']);
            // says onLookupLoad: undefined
    }
}

$(document).bind("pageload", function(event, data) {
    init(data.url);
});

window.onload = init;
```

`init(url)` calls `onDeviceReady()` which calls `executeCallback()`

lookup.html includes the following line inside `<div data-role="page">`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/lookup.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think I know what is wrong but I need to see what your script tag looks like. Post some code. Also can you link to the "20 recipes" page so I can see what your talking about.

Comment: sure, I added the code to my question, the book is available here: http://www.amazon.com/Recipes-Programming-PhoneGap-Cross-Platform-Development/dp/1449319548

Comment: Oh I thought it was a blog page or something.

Comment: yeah I've got a little bit of buyer's remorse.  I think the callback works, as long as window[functionName] is the correct way to reference a function defined in another script.  It's just that the script tag isn't being parsed after the page is inserted into DOM.

Comment: odd, it works when I load up a webserver and use Ripple Mobile Environment Editor (chrome plugin).  Just not in the andriod emulator.

Comment: On a side note that docs specifically state that jquery mobile 1.1 is not tested with jQuery 1.7.2. The suggested version is 1.7.1. I'm not sure if this will help any but it won't hurt to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems as if the issue was that Eclipse was not generating a new apk.  I guess this is because the assets directory changed, but the src directory had not.  If I delete the apk in the bin folder and run the emulator my code works as designed.